# In reactjs need help tailwindcss flowbite while page routing accordion not working?

Tags: reactjs

App.js code

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="accordion-collapse" data-accordion="collapse">
                  <div className="accordion_item">
                    <h2 className="accordion_title">
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="flex pb-0 px-0 pt-0  items-center justify-between w-full p-5 font-medium text-left"
                        data-accordion-target="#accordion-collapse-body-19"
                        aria-expanded="true"
                        aria-controls="accordion-collapse-body-19"
                      >
                        <span>
                          What is the difference between Web2 and Web3 gaming?
                        </span>
                        <svg
                          data-accordion-icon
                          className="w-3 h-3 rotate-180 shrink-0"
                          aria-hidden="true"
                          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                          fill="none"
                          viewBox="0 0 10 6"
                        >
                          <path
                            stroke="#7bf5fb"
                            strokeLinecap="round"
                            strokeLinejoin="round"
                            strokeWidth={2}
                            d="M9 5 5 1 1 5"
                          />
                        </svg>
                      </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div
                      id="accordion-collapse-body-19"
                      className="hidden accordion_body"
                    >
                      <p className="">
                        To fully understand the main differences between
                        traditional and blockchain gaming, let’s first look at
                        the differences between Web2 and Web3 so we can
                        understand how this can be applied to gaming. &nbsp;{" "}
                        <a href="#" className="text-[#7bf5fb]">
                          Read more.
                        </a>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have install tailwindcss and for flowbite I was using there cdn
 `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.8.0/flowbite.min.js"></script>`

but the problem is while I do page routing by react-router-dom that time  cdn not working and my accordion not working. I want to use static flowbite instant of there react components.
How can I fix flowbite issue so that it will work while page routing?